# Routing Error - No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

I have the following destroy method in my Tracks controller:

```
def destroy
  if params[:product_id].present? 
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @track = @product.tracks.find(params[:id])
    @track.destroy
    redirect_to product_path(@product)  
  elsif params[:release_id].present?         
    @release = Release.find(params[:release_id])
    @track = @release.tracks.find(params[:id])
    @track.destroy
    redirect_to release_path(@release)  
  end
end
```

I can destroy a Release Track using:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', release_track_path(@release,track), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

But I get a routing error " No route matches [POST] "/products/74/tracks/43" " when I try to destroy Product Track:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', product_track_path(@product,track), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :destroy %>
```

I've taken a look at my Routes file and think it's probably an issue there, but having tried a few things i'm stumped! Can anyone help? This is driving me crazy. I'm using the same if els on my create method and it works fine for both Release Track and Product Track.

Here's my routes.rb (I suspect this is a big mess!)

```
Dashboard::Application.routes.draw do

get "home/index"
root :to => "home#index"
get "tracks/new"
get "tracks/create"
get "tracks/update"
get "tracks/edit"
get "tracks/destroy"
get "tracks/show"
get "tracks/index"
get "help/index"

resources :helps
resources :roles
resources :labels
devise_for :users
resources :users

resources :releases do
  resources :artists
  resources :tracks
  resources :products do
    resources :tracks
    resources :itunes_data
      end
end

resources :itunes_data

resources :tracks do
  collection { post :sort }
end

resources :products do
  resources :tracks
  collection do
  get 'schedulecsv'
  get 'schedule'
  get 'new_releases'
  get 'active_lines'
  get 'deleted_lines'
  get 'gemsetup'
  get 'amazonsetup'
  get 'search'
  end  
end

resources :artists
end
```

Comment: It looks like you are using `:method => :delete` on your Release method but `:method => :destroy` on Track. Is that an artifact of your debugging?

Comment: Ha! Now I feel stupid! Guess it just takes another set of eyes sometimes huh! Much appreicated, thanks!!

Comment: No problem... I do that all the time... the other thing I do is debug for a while trying a few things and then post the debug attempt making things even more confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up :delete and :destroy and the second line. :method expects an HTTP verb, so it should be :delete.

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage your controllers in a much more maintainable way, you should really checkout the [ressource_controller](https://github.com/jamesgolick/resource_controller). It hides all the standard stuff away and lets you concentrate on the stuff you want to customize.